# Is there a way to profit from this gaming problem

Tags: probability

So lets imagine there is a game.

In this game:

> Players place coins into slots and win a multiplier of the coins in that slot
>
> Players can place any amount of coins in a slot
>
> Players can place coins in any amount of slots (5 slots total)

The slots are:

> 0.04 probability of winning 20 * amount + initial bet
>
> 0.08 probability of winning 10 * amount + initial bet
>
> 0.16 probability of winning 5 * amount + initial bet
>
> 0.24 probability of winning 3 * amount + initial bet
>
> 0.48 of 1 * amount + initial bet

How would I go about calculating the amount of coins to place on each slot to guarantee/maximise winnings.

Answer (score 4):

Start by evaluating the expected return of a bet of $1$ on each slot independently.  You should discover that they are all losing bets.  Any combination of losing bets is still a losing bet by the linearity of expectation.  The way to maximize your winnings is not to play.

This looks like a commercial game.  If so, the easiest way to answer is to trust the house has figured the odds correctly and in their favor.

Comment: It's part of a video game, so I was hoping they maybe hadn't fully thought it through,

Comment: So for the last slot, you have $0.48$ chance of receiving $2$ and $0.52$ chance of receiving $0$.  The expected return is then $0.48\cdot 2=0.96$ and you lose $4\%$ of your bet for each coin you deposit.  The calculation for the other slots is similar.and they are all losing.  The first two lose more, while the last three all have $4\%$ loss.  Don't play.